# Parse Fortran String Like A File

Tags: string, fortran

I want to pass a string from C to Fortran and then process it line-by-line as if I was reading a file.  Is this possible?

**Example String - contains newlines**

```
File description: this file contains stuff
3 Values
  1     Description
  2     Another description
  3     More text
```

Then, I would like to parse the string line-by-line, like a file. Similar to this:

```
subroutine READ_STR(str, len)
character str(len),desc*70

read(str,'(a)') desc
read(str,*) n
do 10 i=1,n
read(str,*) parm(i)
10    continue
```

Comment: The most obvious suggestion is to write to a file in C and read that in Fortran :-).  Assuming Unix, a more efficient option that a normal file could be to use a FIFO — call `mkfifo()` in C, in Fortran you can open the resulting special file normally.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at using a temp file (must be cross-platform).

Comment: If you pass the string to Fortran, and write it from there into a scratch file, this should be cross-platform compatible as well, I believe. You could then just read back from that scratch file unit as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without significant "manual" intervention.  There are a couple of issues:

- The newline character has no special meaning in an internal file.  Records in an internal file correspond to elements in an array.  You would either need to first manually preprocess your character scalar into an array, or use a single READ that skipped over the newline characters.
- If you did process the string into an array, then internal files do not maintain a file position between parent READ statements.  You would need to manually track the current record yourself, or process the entire array with a single READ statement that accessed multiple records.

If you have variable width fields, then writing a format specification to process everything in a single READ could be problematic, though this depends on the details of the input.

Comment: Sounds complicated... what about the example input above, do you see any way to parse this string?  Just need to get the first line's description and the first integer on the rest of the lines.  Or can't you tokenize on newlines?

Comment: With an explicit format specification, you can't tokenise on any character - explicitly formatted input is inherently character position based.  List directed formatting has the concept of a value separator, but that does not [necessarily] include a newline character (newline is not in the Fortran character set).  List directed formatting also has a number of other features that may make it unsuitable.